# SSH into private server without key

Tags: linux, ssh

I am attempting to SSH into an external server to retrieve our DB and DB info. The server admin has provided us with the IP address, port number, username and password. I have not been able to SSH into the server, however.

I am doing the following:

```
ssh root@123.456.789.1011 -p 12345
```

The password prompt comes up, and I enter the password (which I am certain is the correct one) and get the following prompt:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I don't have the private SSH key as this is not my server. Do I have to get that from the admin, or should this current method work? I am on a new box, so do I have to create a public key for my machine first?

Comment: You can use verbosity arguments to ssh (`-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv` depending on how verbose you want) to get debugging output and see where this is failing. Without that or the server's sshd config this is hardly possible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login is rejected. There are two options:

- the password is incorrect (most likely)
- the server is misconfigured and failing (less likely)

There's nothing from your side that you can fix. Request a new password, and when the problem repeats request someone from their side verifies it really works.